# How do I connect to my local PC with apache?

Tags: apache, webserver

[my browser shows me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEPAY.png)

I just downloaded apache2 and installed it.
I've try to connect to my local PC webpage which is in htdocs but browser cannot connect to PC.

What did I lost?

Comment: Check if Apache is actually listening on port 8080. The default Apache port is 80.

Comment: Is a firewall blocking port 8080? As said, default port is 80 anyway